# Unable to invoke journey in SFMC based on Data entry in Data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

Actually I have custom landing pages to insert/update subscriber in shared data extension and having a journey to trigger an email depends on data entry in DE.
For now, journey has shared DE as entry source and one decision split to validate particular field value while data entry and then it triggers an email. I can't see any entries in the journey and new to journey builder. I don't know what I missing?

Comment: You might wanna check the "history" of that particular journey to get more infos. Maybe you see some errors there.

Comment: @JohannesSchapdick, I already check "history", Nothing is there, I can't see any error either.

Comment: Can you please share a snapshot of your journey. Also, how have you scheduled your journey to run? It would be helpful if you share the snapshot. Thanks.

Comment: @KratiGarg, I'm push data from landing pages that contain form using ampscript & ssjs. Schedule info
START -On Activation
Repeat -Never
AUTOMATION STATUS -Running

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple causes why Journey Builder isn't allowing those Contacts to enter.

Since there isn't really much to go on from your post, start off by checking the basic requirements.

- Data Extension needs to be marked as Sendable.
- Check that your Data Extension contains Subscriber Key and Email field which is marked as `EmailAddress` type.
- In your case the Entry Data Source processing needs to be configured as [Evaluate All Records](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_manage_audience_data.htm&type=5).

While probably not the case here, it may also be a *High Water Mark* problem. Was new data added to the data extension?
If not, the Interaction activity may be running as intended, but not detecting new rows because they were not added.

Journey Builder tracks the last event processed for the event source Data Extension to prevent individual events from being injected into an interaction more than once. This is known as the *High Water Mark*. When the event is run, only records in the event source data extension above the *High Water Mark* will be processed. Records below the *High Water Mark* will be ignored.

This becomes problematic if an event source data extension has a primary key set on the field related to Subscriber Key. If an import or query activity is updating records in the event source data extension, they will not be assigned a new row in the data extension. This means that for contacts who may now meet filter criteria for the trigger, but who did not on previous runs of the entry event, they will still not be injected since they fall below the *High Water Mark*.

- [Journey Builder Data Extension as Entry Source](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_data_extension.htm&type=5)
- [Optimize Journey Builder Performance](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_optimize_sending_in_journey_builder.htm&type=5)